# Selfadjoint Operator: Basic Criterion

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, adjoint-operators

For symmetric operators one has:
$$A\text{ symmetric}:\quad\mathcal{R}(A\pm\imath)=\mathcal{H}\implies A^*=A$$
How to prove this in an unveiling way?

Comment: What is $\iota$?

Comment: Imaginary unit implemented in latex by iota and encoded in \imath ...I know it's not the best way to implement it but ok

Comment: I don't understand your notation.

Comment: So it's $i$ times the identity? You can't prove it, since e.g. $\mathcal{R}(A\pm \imath) = \mathcal{H}$ for $A = 3i\cdot I$.

Comment: Yes i*1! But isn't your example actually self adjoint...

Comment: $(iI)^* = -iI$.

Comment: Oh right I forgot: Let $A$ be a symmetric operator. I corrected it in the question...

Comment: Please note: You cannot define an adjoint for $A$ until you know it is densely-defined. So this issue really should be addressed before discussing $A^{\star}$.

Comment: You have missed a subtle and important point in closing Tobias Hurth's question: In his question $A$ is not assumed to be densely-defined, which means that $A^{\star}$ is not well-defined, and the answer you selected here is not valid without knowing that.

Comment: Yep sure the adjoint requires densely-defined in order to be well defined. From there it's a rather interesting point that densely-defined already follows from the range argument plus symmetry... Which question do you mean from Tobias Hurth?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $A$ is symmetric<sup>(1)</sup>, we have

$$A \pm \imath \subset A^\ast \pm \imath = (A\mp\imath)^\ast.\tag{1}$$

Since $\mathcal{R}(A\pm\imath) = \mathcal{H}$ it follows that $\mathcal{R}(A^\ast \pm \imath) = \mathcal{H}$. Since $A^{\ast\ast}\subset A^\ast$, the operators $A^\ast \pm \imath$ are injective, thus bijective. But a proper suboperator of a bijective operator cannot be surjective, hence the inclusion in $(1)$ cannot be proper and in fact $A\pm\imath = A^\ast \pm \imath$, whence $A = A^\ast$.

---

<sup>(1)</sup> If the definition of symmetry is $\langle Ax,y\rangle = \langle x, Ay\rangle$ for all $x,y\in \mathcal{D}(A)$ and not $A\subset A^\ast$, the existence of the adjoint, equivalently the denseness of $\mathcal{D}(A)$, needs to be deduced from $\mathcal{R}(A+\imath) = \mathcal{H}$ as pointed out and done by [TAE](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/112478/t-a-e). For that, one picks $x\in \mathcal{D}(A)^\perp$ and by the surjectivity, one can write $x = (A+\imath)y$ for a $y\in\mathcal{D}(A)$. Then

$$0 = \langle x,y\rangle = \langle (A+\imath)y,y\rangle = \langle Ay,y\rangle + i\lVert y\rVert^2$$

implies $y = 0$ and thus $x = 0$ since $\langle Ay,y\rangle \in\mathbb{R}$. So $\mathcal{D}(A)$ is dense, $A^\ast$ exists, and $A\subset A^\ast$.

Comment: Thats a nice proof I was thinking of - thx!

Comment: But do you really need that $A^{**}\subset A^*$ and how do you use it then? I mean we know that $\mathcal{N}(A^*)=\mathcal{R}(A)^\perp$.

Comment: $A^{\ast\ast} \subset A^\ast$ was just the most obvious (to me) way of showing that $A^\ast \pm \imath$ is injective that came to mind. Anything that shows that $A^\ast$ cannot have purely imaginary eigenvalues except $0$ would do.

Comment: By the way that is a pretty application of the pigeonhole principle...

Comment: Did you address the issue that $A$ is not assumed to be densely-defined? $A^{\star}$ is not well-defined unless $A$ is densely-defined.

Comment: @T.A.E. The definition of symmetric I'm used to is $T\subset T^\ast$, it didn't occur to me that another definition could be in use.

Comment: Symmetric normally means $(Ax,y)=(x,Ay)$ for all $x,y \in \mathcal{D}(A)$. Adjoint of $A$ requires a dense domain--otherwise it is not well-defined. Symmetric does not require that. Part of what is interesting is that the domain is dense if $A$ is symmetric and $(A-iI)$ is surjective.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can go one step further. If $A$ is symmetric with $\mathcal{R}(A-iI)=X$,  then $A$ has a dense domain. And $A=A^{\star}$ on that domain if $\mathcal{R}(A+iI)=X$ also holds.

To see that $A$ has a dense domain here, suppose that $y \perp\mathcal{D}(A)$ and write $y=(A-iI)x$. Then
$$
           0 = (y,x)=((A-iI)x,x)=(Ax,x)-i(x,x).
$$
Both the real and imaginary parts must be $0$, which forces $x=0$. So $\mathcal{D}(A)^{\perp}=\{0\}$, or $\mathcal{D}(A)^{c}=X$.

Next, to show that $A=A^{\star}$, suppose that $y \in \mathcal{D}(A^{\star})$. Write $(A^{\star}+iI)y=(A+iI)z$  for some $z\in\mathcal{D}(A)$ (this can be done because $A+iI$ is surjective.) Then
$$
          ((A-iI)x,y)=(x,(A^{\star}+iI)y)=(x,(A+iI)z)=((A-iI)x,z).
$$
Because $\mathcal{R}(A-iI)=X$, then it follows that $y=z \in \mathcal{D}(A)$; in other words, $\mathcal{D}(A^{\star})\subseteq \mathcal{D}(A)$. The opposite inclusion $\mathcal{D}(A)\subseteq \mathcal{D}(A^{\star})$ follows from the symmetry of $A$. So $\mathcal{D}(A)=\mathcal{D}(A^{\star})$, which is enough to prove that $A=A^{\star}$.

Comment: @Freeze_S : Thank you. It's also useful when studying symmetric differential operators because very often you can use classical results to show density of the range of $(A\pm iI)$ because of classical solvability and then you get density of the complicated domains for free. For example, you can show that periodic absolutely continuous $f\in L^{2}[0,2\pi]$ with $f'\in L^{2}$ is dense in $L^{2}$ by showing that $(-if'\pm if)=g$ can be solved for such $f$ whenever $g\in L^{2}[0,2\pi]$. Otherwise, it's a struggle to prove density directly. The arguments extend to $L^{p}$, $1 \le p < \infty$ too.

Comment: Oh man this is great - you know I was just struggling the whole night with pain in the ### mollifiers in order to prove Stone's theorem until I now finally realized it already suffices to check full range ^^ - great!!!

Comment: @Freeze_S : This works great for classical Sturm-Liouville operators where you have a Green solution. You get density of a complicated domain with periodic/separated endpoint conditions. If fact, with symmetric, it suffices to show that $(A\pm iI)$ have dense ranges. So then you can switch to continuous functions $f$ in $L^{2}$ and use classical theorems to show that $(A\pm iI)g=f$ are solvable. This is because $A$ symmetric implies $\|(A\pm iI)f\| \ge \|f\|$; these $(A\pm iI)$ always have bounded inverses on their ranges, which extend by continuity to all of the space if the ranges are dense.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A\subseteq A^*$ (because $A$ is symmetric), it's enough to prove that $D(A^*)\subseteq D(A)$.

Take $y\in D(A^*)=D(A^*\pm\mathrm i)$.

As $(A^*\pm\mathrm i)y\in\mathcal R(A^*\pm\mathrm i)\subseteq \mathcal{H}=\mathcal R(A\pm \mathrm i)$, there exists $x\in D(A\pm\mathrm i)$ such that
$$(A^*\pm\mathrm i)y=(A\pm\mathrm i)x=(A^*\pm\mathrm i)x$$
and thus
$$y-x\in \ker(A^*\pm \mathrm i)=\mathcal R(A\mp\mathrm i)^{\perp}=\mathcal{H}^\perp=\{0\}.$$
So, $y=x\in D(A\pm\mathrm i)=D(A)$.