# Discrete Derivative: Closure?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

**Problem**

Given the Hilbert space $\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$.

Consider the operators:
$$T_0:\ell^2_0(\mathbb{N})\to\ell^2(\mathbb{N}):\quad T_0(a_k)_k:=(ka_k)_k$$
$$\mathcal{D}(T):=\{(a_k)_k:\|T(a_k)_k\|:=\sum_{k=0}^\infty|ka_k|^2<\infty\}$$
Then one has the closure:
$$\overline{T_0}=T=\overline{T}$$
Is this true and how to prove this?

**Attempt**

Hypothetically it is a core since:
$$\varphi\in\mathcal{D}(T):\quad(\varphi_n,T_0\varphi_n)\to(\varphi,T\varphi)\quad(\varphi_n:=(a_0,\ldots,a_n,0,\ldots))$$
But was the operator closable at all?

Comment: The operator $T_{0}$ is symmetric, and it is trivial to check that $T_{0}\pm iI$ are surjective. Therefore, automatically $T_{0}$ is (a) densely-defined and (b) selfajdoint (which implies closed.)

Comment: I wrote $T_{0}$ but meant $T$.

Comment: @T.A.E.: I was already wondering... :)

Comment: @T.A.E.: Woohooo I did check that it is selfadjoint. :D Thanks so much!!!

Comment: You're welcome. There's another one of those posts that disappeared when a user disappeared. :)

Comment: @T.A.E.: Do you remember what it was about?

Comment: If $T$ is symmetric on its domain (not assumed dense) and if $T\pm iI$ are surjective, then $T$ is densely-defined and selfadjoint.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Oh yes I remember both answered by you. ;) Look for: [Selfadjointness: Basic Criterion](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/832944/79762)

Comment: Thank you. The proof that the domain is dense is so easy using that method, and doing it any other way is often nearly impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can consider every sequence $(a_k)_k$ as a function $\mathbb N_0\to\mathbb C$. Then
$$\mathcal{D}(T)=\{(a_k)_k\ \colon\sum_{k=0}^\infty|ka_k|^2<\infty\mbox{ and } \sum_{k=0}^\infty|a_k|^2<\infty\}=\\ =\{(a_k)_k\ \colon||(a_k)||_{graph}^2=\sum_{k=0}^\infty(1+k^2)|a_k|^2<\infty\}=L^2(\mathbb N_0,\mu),$$
where $\mu$ is the discrete measure defined by $\mu(\{k\})={1+k^2}$ and $||\cdot||_{graph}$ is the graph norm, which is equal to the Hilbert space norm in $L^2(\mathbb N_0,\mu)$. Now $L^2(\mathbb N_0,\mu)$ is complete as a Hilbert space. Hence $D(T)$ is complete with respect to the graph norm, which is equivalent to $T=\overline T$. Note that every dense linear subspace in $L^2(\mathbb N_0,\mu)$ is a core for $T$, hence $\overline T_0=T$.

Comment: Interesting idea!!